SwiftUI .labeledContentStyle failed with errors using swift's ?:, It works using if/else. Why?
Using Xcode 16
Added .labeledContentStyle to style LabeledContent() as in the code [1]. It generated the errors in [2]. Rewrote the ?: into if/else in [3], and this works. I had believed these were functionally equivalent. The LabeledContentStyle structs are in [4] and [5] (there are more styles, just giving two of them).
All the styles are of type LabeledContentStyle, so why are they not equivalent?
Can someone explain?
[1]
LabeledContent("Updated", value: domain.whoisUpdateDate)
  .labeledContentStyle(
    domain.whoisUpdateDate == "not resolved" ? .errorStyle :
    domain.whoisUpdateDate == domainParent.whoisUpdateDate ? .normalStyle : .changedStyle )

[2]
Member 'normalStyle' in 'ErrorLabeledContentStyle' produces result of type 'NormalLabeledContentStyle', but context expects 'ErrorLabeledContentStyle'

Static property 'normalStyle' requires the types 'ErrorLabeledContentStyle' and 'NormalLabeledContentStyle' be equivalent

Member 'changedStyle' in 'ErrorLabeledContentStyle' produces result of type 'ChangedLabeledContentStyle', but context expects 'ErrorLabeledContentStyle'

Static property 'changedStyle' requires the types 'ErrorLabeledContentStyle' and 'ChangedLabeledContentStyle' be equivalent

[3]
if domain.whoisUpdateDate == "not resolved" {
  LabeledContent("Updated", value:       domain.whoisUpdateDate).labeledContentStyle(.errorStyle)
  } else if domain.whoisUpdateDate != domainParent.whoisUpdateDate {
    LabeledContent("Updated", value:  domain.whoisUpdateDate).labeledContentStyle(.changedStyle)
  } else {
    LabeledContent("Updated", value: domain.whoisUpdateDate).labeledContentStyle(.normalStyle)
}


See the first duplicate target for how to make your styles dynamic. See Demystifying SwiftUI to see why using an if...else is not equivalent to using a ternary operator. In particular, if...else destroys the structural identity of the view. See the second duplicate target to see how one might preserve structural identity in a dynamic style.

Moved logic for same, changed, and error styles to inside the makeBody() function of LabeledContentStyle structure. All is working now.
